# Writing data to InfluxDB results in InfluxDBServerError 'short write'

Tags: python, influxdb

I have several csv files which I import in Python and write to InfluxDB.
Writing of the data succeeds up until a specific date.
After that date I get an InfluxDBServerError 'short write' and nothing is written anymore.

I read csv data in a dataframe and write that dataframe to InfluxDB.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'csv/{args.name}.csv', sep=';', index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
influxdb.write_points(df, name, batch_size=1000)
```

If I try another InfluxDB database all rows are written without any issues.

We are using InfluxDB 1.8